# WPF Checkbox IsEnabled Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm afraid I have a dumb question that I can't seem to find an answer for.

I'm trying to implement a filter for tags: it has a textbox that you can enter tags in, as well as Tagged and Untagged checkboxes.  I want that Untagged should become disabled if the textbox has any text in it.

I thought this would be easy:

My ViewModel:

```
private bool _untaggedEnabled = true;
public UntaggedEnabled {
    get { 
        return _untaggedEnabled; 
    } set {
        _untaggedEnabled = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UntaggedEnabled));
    } 
}
```

My View's CodeBehind:
(yes, I could do this in xaml alone, but if I were good at xaml I wouldn't be here!)

```
private void tagsList_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e) {
    _viewModel.UntaggedEnabled = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tagsList.Text);
}
```

And my View:

```
<TextBox x:Name="tagsList" Text="{Binding TagsList}" />
<CheckBox Content="Untagged" IsEnabled="{Binding UntaggedEnabled}" IsChecked="{Binding Untagged} />
```

There's a bunch of other controls and bound properties in the component, all of which are working fine, except this `IsEnabled`.

I can pepper debug outputs all over the place and everything is being updated accordingly, when it's supposed to, but nothing on the actual IsEnabled property.

I've also added `Mode=TwoWay` and `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to the IsEnabled xaml, to no avail.

I feel like this should be really easy.  Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: Have you set a [DataContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.datacontext(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @Link yes - there's numerous other controls all bound to the same datacontext/VM that are working fine.

Comment: There is no event declaration in TextBox :)

Comment: @ValeraScherbakov - there is, I didn't show it for brevity.  Note the question says that I can put debug outputs everywhere and all values are updating as expected _except_ the visual state of the checkbox.

Comment: And your ViewModel implements INotifyPropertyChanged? Only the event is not enough

Comment: I don't see any problems in this code, except for TextBox hasn't TextChanged = "tagsList_TextChanged" declaration.
But you said, you removed it for brevity...

Comment: Try IsEnabled="{Binding UntaggedEnabled, Mode=TwoWay}" - For some controls it has to be specified

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem with this ViewModel to bind (and get rid of the view code-behind)

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }

    protected bool Set<T>( ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null )
    {
        if ( Equals( storage, value ) ) return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged( propertyName );
        return true;
    }

    string _tags;
    bool _untagged;

    public string Tags
    {
        get => _tags; set
        {
            if ( Set( ref _tags, value ) )
            {
                OnPropertyChanged( nameof( UntaggedEnabled ) );
            }
        }
    }
    public bool Untagged { get => _untagged; set => Set( ref _untagged, value ); }
    public bool UntaggedEnabled => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( Tags );
}
```

View:

```
<TextBox 
    Text="{Binding Tags,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<CheckBox 
    Content="Untagged" 
    IsChecked="{Binding Untagged, Mode=TwoWay}" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding UntaggedEnabled, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Comment: I had already been implementing INotifiyPropertyChanged, but when I added the `OnPropertyChanged(nameof(UntaggedEnabled))` to the setter for the `TagsList`, it works.  I have no idea why that property's own setter wasn't handling it, but anyway, I can at least move on now, even if I don't full understand.  Thanks

Comment: Seems you have **two** instances of your viewmodel. One is assigned to the views DataContext and the other is the one you set the property in code behind (stored in _viewModel)

Answer (score 0):

> Untagged should become disabled if the textbox has any text in it

This can be easily achieved without any code in the View:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding TagsList, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<CheckBox Content="Untagged" IsEnabled="{Binding IsUntaggedEnabled}"/>
```

but with some in the ViewModel:

```
string _tagList;
public string TagList
{
    get { return _tagList; }
    set
    {
        _tagList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(); // [CallerMemberName]
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsUntaggedEnabled));
    }
}

public bool IsUntaggedEnabled => TagList != "";
```